# Sometimes AJAX calls don't work

Tags: jquery, ajax

We are using jquery to make ajax calls. Most of the times, the calls work fine. Sometimes the same calls give xhr status = 0, xhr.readystatus = 0 and xhr.statusText = "error".

```
"xhr":{"status":0,"statusText":"error","responseText":"","readyState":0}
```

What does this mean? Is there a issue on browser side or server side?

Thanks

Comment: There is really really little information to help you here

Answer (score 0):

*Typically* when xhr.status returns `0`, it means that there is no Network Connection found.

There's a few reasons you could be getting it as well:

- Potentially from a failed cross-domain requests.
- Failed localhost request
- A user trying to leave a page (back-button, etc) while a Request hasn't finished.

Comment: Ran burp proxy on my client to see how the requests are going. It looks like the ajax calling is falling back to error function with the said statuses even before the actual call is made. The actual call is made after 2 secs which I can see in burp logs.